# RadioGroup doesn't transfer data or open the next Activity

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

I'm trying to make a questionaire app on Android Studio but the app closes whenever I press the proceed button on the first question page.

I used a RadioGroup for each question and each RadioButton contains a number that will be transferred to the next Activity. At the end of the questionaire, it will show a result based on the number that was calculated from the answers.

This is what I did but I feel like I'm missing something. Can anyone help me or even simplified the code? Thank you!

FIRST QUESTION CLASS:

```
package com.example.hobbytest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class first_question extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_question);

    }

        public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.activeButton:
                    if(checked){
                        getScore(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.passiveButton:
                    if(checked){
                        getScore(9);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.bothButton:
                    if(checked){
                        getScore(18);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
            public void getScore(int first_score) {
                Button proceed_button = findViewById(R.id.proceed_button);
                RadioGroup first_answers = findViewById(R.id.firstAnswers);

                proceed_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // When proceed button is clicked,
                        // Get the Radio Button which is set
                        // If no Radio Button is set, -1 will be returned
                        int selectedId = first_answers.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        if (selectedId == -1) {
                            Toast.makeText(first_question.this,
                                    "No answer has been selected",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(first_question.this, second_question.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("First Score", first_score);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                        }
    }

} );
}
}
```

FIRST Q ACTIVITY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".first_question">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="414dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="627dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/idlestopper"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- Right most TextView -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.859"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/view_icon"
                tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,ImageContrastCheck,RedundantDescriptionCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="81dp"
        android:src="@drawable/triple_circles"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:text="@string/first_question"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/firstAnswers"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/proceed_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.397">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/activeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/active"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/passiveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/passive"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bothButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/both"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/proceed_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/proceed"
        android:textColor="#5D4037"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.862" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SECOND QUESTION CLASS:

```
package com.example.hobbytest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class second_question extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int first_score = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("First Score"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_question);

    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.shortButton:
                if(checked){
                    getScore(1);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mediumButton:
                if(checked){
                    getScore(9);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.longButton:
                if(checked){
                    getScore(18);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    public void getScore(int second_score) {
        Button proceed_button = findViewById(R.id.proceed_button);
        RadioGroup second_answers = findViewById(R.id.secondAnswers);


        proceed_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int third_score = first_score + second_score;


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // When proceed button is clicked,
                // Get the Radio Button which is set
                // If no Radio Button is set, -1 will be returned
                int selectedId = second_answers.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if (selectedId == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(second_question.this,
                            "No answer has been selected",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(second_question.this, third_question.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Third Score", third_score);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

SECOND QUESTION ACTIVITY:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".second_question">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="414dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="627dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/idlestopper"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- Right most TextView -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.859"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/view_icon"
                tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,ImageContrastCheck,RedundantDescriptionCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="81dp"
        android:src="@drawable/triple_circles"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:text="@string/second_question"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/secondAnswers"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/proceed_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.397">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/shortButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/short_ans"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mediumButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/medium_ans"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/longButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="@string/long_ans"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/proceed_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/proceed"
        android:textColor="#5D4037"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.862" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```